# firebase deleting items belongs to a folder or category

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

this is my first question. if i make a mistake, sorry from the beginning. i am newbie at firebase and react native. i searched and i couldent find my answers anywhere.

i made a to do list. i searched about structure of database and understood that the structure must be flatten and i made a structure like that:

[data structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzGZ6.png)

data structure:

```
database {
    folders: {
            folder_name: folder1,
            messages: {
                      message1: true, (uid of this message)
                      message2: true  (uid of this message)
                      }
             }

    messages: {
            message1 {
              message_content: this is a to do item1,
              time: 1212221321,
              folder: folder1 (uid of this folder)  
              }
                     }

            message2 {
              message_content: this is a to do item2,
              time: 1212221321,
              folder: folder1 (uid of this folder)  
              }

            message3 {
              message_content: this is a to do item3,
              time: 1212221321,
              folder: folder2 (this message is in another folder)  
              }
              ......
          }
}
```

as you see, when i add a message in a folder, the folder contains message uid numbers in it. and each message contains an object property as folder uid (which folder this message in).

questions:

1: is this structure type right way? or should starters use another structure?

2: well, i m planning to turn the message id to false in folders (klasorler) when user delete a message. but i dont know what should i do when user delete a folder.(in this case, deleting folder 1..if folder one i must delete only message1 and message2) should i get all of message id's in folder and start a loop and delete messages one by one? (i mean loop in react native side)... or is there any shorter and smarter way in firebase with firebase methods ?

i hope i explained myself well :)

Comment: In general it's good to include s snippet of your Firebase structure in the question as text please, no images or links. If you want to remove the children of a node, you can simply delete the parent node which removes all of the children or in this case, setting the parent node to false will also overwrite all of the children. As far as the structure being 'right', only you can determine that once you've written some code and see if it works.

Comment: ok i edited the question and add the text of data structure.sorry for that. but i allready can remove a node. in this question ; i am asking that; there are two messages in folder one. if someone delete the folder 1, how can i delete message1 and message2 in messages object? (or many many messages belongs to folder1)...i must make a loop or another way ? i must delete the messages in messages object fisrt (which belongs to folder1), then remove the folder1 ?

Comment: The same thing applies. I you set messages = "" for example, that will delete all of the child messages. That will actually remove the messages node entirely as nodes cannot be "". If you want to keep the node, set messages = false, which will also remove all of the child nodes.

Comment: thank you for your replies...why should i turn messages to false or empty string? messages object isnt a child of folders. messages object and folders object are siblings. in this case, the two messages are relative to folder1 but think that there is a third message and it's reference is folder2.  when i delete the folder1, i have to find a way to delete only messages relative to folder1..edit: i edited the question

Comment: You have two nodes with a key of *messages*  1) database/folders/messages  and 2) database/messages which is where the confusion is. I understand now... upon removing database/folders/message you then want to remove the corresponding message node from database/messages. Are the folders and messages a 1-many relationship? i.e. why are the messages being stored in a separate node? If so, is there a reason you can't just store the message within database/folders/messages?

Comment: oh you are right. i named my two of stuff same= messages...sorry ... there isnt a reason that i cant store my messages in folders node...i just saw a firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data   ....here says make your structure like flatten data... maybe i made a mistake i dont know. that s why i asked first question :)

Comment: That's called [denormalizing data](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) and it's very important. However, there are situations where it's not needed. As far as I can tell you don't need to denormalize the data - just store the messages with the folder. That will make it simple to delete them.

Comment: ok i guess i dont need to denormalize that data as you say. i will check the denormalization chepter again. i guess i got it wrong :) thank you for your replies so much.